# How can i make a switch button that each click it will do something else?

Tags: javascript

I'm calling this function from inside a button onclick event:

```
function pauseSlide() {
                clearInterval(sint);
                setInterval(slideUpdate, 1000); paused(clearInterval)
            }
```

And i want that on the first click to do the clearInterval(sint);
And if i click on the button again then only do the setInterval(slideUpdate, 1000);

Like a switch.

In csharp for example you do it like this: CelsiusFahrenheit = !CelsiusFarenheit;
So one click the boolean CelsiusFahrenheit is true and next click it's false then again true and so on....

This is the javascript button onclick event:

```
var
                    slideShow = d.getElementById('slideShow'),
                    slideCounter = make('div', false, {id: 'slideCounter'}),
                    slideControls = make('div', false, {id: 'slideControls'}),
                    slidePrev = make('a', 'Previous Slide', {
                        onclick: function (e) {
                            controlEvent(e, prevSlide);
                        },
                        className: 'previous',
                        href: '#'
                    }, slideControls),
                    slideNext = make('a', 'Next Slide', {
                        onclick: function (e) {
                            controlEvent(e, nextSlide);
                        },
                        className: 'next',
                        href: '#'
                    }, slideControls),
                    slidePause = make('a', 'Pause Slide', {
                        onclick: function (e) {
                            controlEvent(e, pauseSlide);
                        },
                        className: 'pause',
                        href: '#'
                    }, slideControls)
```

I did that if i click the Pause Slide button it will call the function pauseSlide
And inside pauseSlide i want to make the switch one click to call clearInterval another click will call setInterval.

I have this function also:

```
function slideUpdate() {
                if (swapCounter--)
                    showCounter();
                else
                    nextSlide();
            }
```

And if i click the button a lot it's just making the countdown to move faster each time.

If it will help or needed this is the complete code with all buttons events:

[JS](http://pastebin.com/FAGhGrHD)

Comment: what about a third click, or a 4th click etc..?

Comment: james indeed you right that's also a problem how to make the pause continue button to work like this even after the 5th or the 100th click.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few ways to do this. The best is probably to keep a boolean variable such as "isPaused" and flip that back and forth as needed. Wrap your click logic in a conditional dependent on that variable.

BTW you can't detect whether an interval is running or has been cleared. Even if you could, it would be harder to read and understand what was going on. I'd prefer a semantic variable as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is example of handle multiactions in loop, main idea is to place actions to array and shift/push them to cycle.

```
var actions = [

function () {
    console.log(1);
    $(this).next().fadeOut(100);
},

function () {
    console.log(2);
    $(this).next().fadeIn(100);
},

function () {
    console.log(3);
    $(this).next().slideUp();
},

function () {
    console.log(4);
    $(this).next().slideDown();
}];



$('.multiact').each(function (i, e) {
    $(e).data('actions', actions.concat());
}).click(function (e) {
    var acts = $(this).data('actions'),
        act = acts.shift();
    acts.push(act);
    act.call(this, e);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8tgxpedq/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var prevClicked = false;
           var my_slide_timer;
function pauseSlide() {
            if(!prevClicked){
                clearInterval(my_slide_timer);
                prevClicked = true;
             }else{
                  my_slide_timer = setInterval(slideUpdate, period); 
                  prevClicked = false;
             }
 }
```

This did the trick.